# How to read this response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have this string as part of response from a url:

`b'{"warnings":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid number"}],"errors":[{"code":4,"message":"No recipients specified"}],"status":"failure"}'`

I've been trying to remove the `b` and read into a JSON parser, but getting an error.
My objective it to read the code and message of warnings and errors if they exist.

I tried:

```
import json
import requests    
if "warnings" in response:
    response = response[1:]
    print(response)
json_data = json.loads(response)
print(json_data)
```

But I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-17ab7818300e> in <module>()
      5     response = response[1:]
      6     print(response)
----> 7 json_data = json.loads(response)
      8 print(json_data)

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

When I try without slicing off the first character,

`JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Are you sure you have a string starting with `b` and not bytes object?

Comment: this looks like a python literal, you can use `literal_eval()` on it to make it into an object

Comment: Are you sure that you are really processing the example byte string you provided ? Have no issues to pass this to `json.loads`.

Answer (score 1):

`response = response[1:]` removes the first character from your json string, which turns it invalid. To remove the `warnings` entry create a dictionary first, then remove it:

```
response = b'{"warnings":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid number"}],"errors":[{"code":4,"message":"No recipients specified"}],"status":"failure"}'

result = json.loads(response)
if "warnings" in result:
    del result["warnings"]

print(result)
```

prints

```
{'errors': [{'code': 4, 'message': 'No recipients specified'}], 'status': 'failure'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might helps you:

```
decoded_response = response.decode()
data = json.loads(decoded_response)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're slicing off the first character. Don't do that. Just pass the whole string to `json.loads`.

Comment: Then, I get `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 130 (char 129)`

Answer (score 0):

It is a byte object, you can decode it to a string using the below function.

```
res=response.decode('utf-8')
data = json.loads(res)
json_data = json.loads(data)
print(json_data)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I get this: `  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    'not {!r}'.format(s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'
`

Answer (score 0):

your response from a url is a byte array. You need to convert it into string object before it can be parsed by Json module.

```
data = json.loads(f.decode())
```